# Display none when the button is click again in Ajax

Tags: ajax, asp.net-mvc

I have been using Ajax to show partial pages in my application.
I would like to ask if it's possible to set the display to none when the user click again the link generated by `@Ajax.ActionLink()`?

Here's my code:

```
@model IEnumerable<RMSystem.Models.rms_referred_vw>

<table id="example">
  <tbody>
    @foreach(var rfp in Model){
      <tr>
        <td>
        @Ajax.ActionLink(Convert.ToString(rfp.rf_id), "Edit_Ref", new { rf_id = rfp.rf_id },
          new AjaxOptions
          {
            HttpMethod = "POST",
            InsertionMode = InsertionMode.InsertBefore,
            UpdateTargetId = "target6",
          }, new  {@style="color:darkblue", title = "Edit Referred Person"})
        </td>
        <td>@Html.DisplayFor(model => rfp.rf_badgeno)</td>
        // more table cells
         <td>
            @Ajax.ActionLink("Details", "Details", new { rf_id = rfp.rf_id },
              new AjaxOptions
              {
                HttpMethod = "GET",
                InsertionMode = InsertionMode.Replace,
                UpdateTargetId = "show",
              }, new  {@style="color:darkblue", title = "Show More Details"})
         </td>
    </tr>
    }
  </tbody>
</table>

<div id="target6"></div>
<div id="show" style="width:250px;height:200px;margin-left:1000px;"></div>
```

That's my code Sir.

Controller:

```
public ActionResult Details(int rf_id = 0)
{
    var check = db.rms_approval_route_vw.Where(s => s.rf_id == rf_id).FirstOrDefault();
    try
    {
        if (check != null)
        {
            return PartialView(check);
        }
    }
    catch (Exception) {
        throw;
    }
    return Content("<script type='text/javascript'>alert('Waiting for regularization.');</script>");
}
```

Comment: Yes its possible. What have you tried?

Comment: Actually, I don't have a little idea on how to implement it since I only use Ajax to show results and nothing else.

Comment: Then at least show your current code including the html for the element your updating

Comment: Which 'button' are you referring to?

Comment: @StephenMuecke,  The one in the ajax link. When I click again that link, the div display should be none.

Comment: I'll edit you question to remove all the irrelevant code and add an answer later (give me 30 minutes)

Comment: Side note. You should be using `[DisplayFormat(NullDisplayText = "None")]` on your properties rather than those awful `if` statements

Comment: @StephenMuecke, Thanks in advance for the answer.
By the way, I'm connecting the database to sql Server, so if I put the data annotations, it will be replaced the next time I will reconnect to the database. Isn't it correct?

Comment: Why don't just disable the button click on first click or store in JavaScript variable that it's already clicked.

Comment: You should be using view models.

Comment: @GuptaAnirudha, that does not clear the existing contents, besides if the user then clicks a the link in another row, the previously clicked link would then need to enabled.

Answer (score 1):

Remove your `@Html.ActionLink()` and replace with (note the code below is for the 2nd link)

```
<td><a href="#" class="details" data-id="@rfp.rf_id">Details</a><td>
```

and add a script

```
var details = $('#show');
$('.details').click(function() {
  var self = $(this);
  // Check if we have already loaded it
  if (self.data('loaded'))
  {
    details.empty(); // clear contents
    self.removeData('loaded'); // signal is no longer loaded
  } else {
    $.get('@Url.Action("Details")', { rf_id: $(this).data('id') }, function(data) {
      details.html(data); // update the DOM
      self.data('loaded', true); // signal its been loaded
    });
  }
});
```

Comment: I'll create a quick test (in case I have a typo)

Comment: Made a small change to simplify it but it works fine - refer this [DotNetFiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/lRN5hV) for an example. Check you console for errors. Perhaps you have not put the script at the bottom of the page or wrapped it in `document.ready()`

Comment: Do I really need to include the bootstrap js?

Comment: No of course not. The only script you require is `jquery-{version}.js` (you can delete the `jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.js` file in your existing view as well)

Comment: In your example, the controller function returns JSON result. Mine is not. Does it matter? 

See edited question.

Comment: Does not make any difference. DotNetFiddle only allows one view so I cannot return a separate partial view so just faked it by returning JSON instead. If its not working for you, you have made a mistake. Use you browser tools - what errors are you getting in the browser console?

Comment: There's no error when I check the console.Basically, the page where this link can be found is a partial view so I transferred the script in the lay out page because the queries are loaded in there.

Comment: Have just seen your edit. Your last line of code - `return Content(..` is pointless and it would not work anyway. If you have no errors in the browser console, put a breakpoint on your script and step through it, or add some `console.log()` statements to help debug it.

Comment: And change you method to `public ActionResult Details(int rf_id) { var check = db.rms_approval....; if (check != null) { return PartialView(check); } else { return new EmptyResult(); } }` (the `try/catch` block is pointless)

Comment: Is there any point anyone ever answering your questions? Good luck getting help in the future.

Comment: thank you so much for the answer. However, I have  a problem. Whenever I click another dialog, it seems like the page isn't updated automatically. I know that there's something to do with rendering the action inside the dialog.

Comment: There is nothing in your code about a dialog. Ask a new question with the relevant details and code. Maybe someone who has not wasted their time helping you previously might answer it. Or maybe you should consider accepted answers to your previous questions that worked (like [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32646631/show-dropdown-list-based-on-the-selected-dropdown) or [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32628473/simple-pop-up-in-jquery-for-multiple-table-rows) or [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32579333/linq-query-results-to-datatable-in-view)